# Один проект из нескольких war файлов

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Добрый день! Использую Spring MVC,Spring Data Jpa, Spring Security. После авторизации на сайте, юзер может может выбрать 1 из 5 модулей для работы. Соответственно хотелось бы, что бы  каждый модуль, был отдельным (отдельный war file, project?), при этом что бы в каждом работал Spring Security, Менеджер сессий.... Можете подсказать, как сконфигурировать проекты? Может тыкните куда почитать. Спасибо

Comment: Может Вам нужен Portlet? Или система единого входа? Посмотрите keycloak.

Comment: Нужно разбить ваше приложения на 5 (спасибо кэп). Каждое должно лежать в своём контексте. Но между ними надо настроить SSO, что является немного затруднительно, если у тебя немного опыта. Собственно это тема отдельного вопроса. В качестве SSO можно использовать к примеру [CAS](https://www.apereo.org/projects/cas). Более проблем не вижу.

Answer (score 1):

Общие библиотеки можно вынести в каталог библиотек сервера приложений. Например, в `tomcat/lib`. Тогда мы можем эти библиотеки исключить из сборки war. В maven для этого нужно указать `scope = provided`.